# Recursive Descent Parser In C - Error while backtracking

Tags: c, parsing, backtrace, recursive-descent

*Implementing a recursive descent parser for the given grammar with the sample input '(a)'. 
The output of this program is to check if the input read by the user is parsed successfully or not. As of how the flow of the program should go for this particular input...*

`main()` calls the start symbol `E() -> T() -> T1()` [ which evaluates to false ] hence tracing back to its parent function `T()` which now calls `T2()` (which also evaluates to false), hence `T() -> T3() -> E() -> E1() -> T() -> T1()` (evaluates to true).

Eventually `E()` should also be true and the last condition `termial(')')` in the statement `return termial('(') && E() && termial(')');` from the function `T3()` should be performed with `')'` as the value for `token`. However, it turns out that `token == '('` still and hence the output of the program results in

> Parsed Unsuccessfully

Not really sure why `token` is not equal to `')'`

```
 //Grammar :
 //E -> T | T + E
 //T -> a | a * T | (E)
 //
 //Input :
 //(a)

#include <stdio.h>

char *next;

int E();
int E1();
int E2();
int T();
int T1();
int T2();
int T3();

int termial(char token){
    return (*next++ == token);
}

int E1(){
    return T();
}

int E2(){
    return T() && termial('+') && E();
}

int E(){
    char *temp = next;
    return (next = temp, E1()) || (next = temp, E2());
}

int T1(){
    return termial('a');
}

int T2(){
    return termial('a') && termial('*') && T();
}

int T3(){
    return termial('(') && E() && termial(')');
}

int T(){
    char *temp = next;
    return (next = temp, T1()) || (next = temp, T2()), (next = temp, T3());
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char str[10];
    int result;
    printf("INPUT a string to be parsed : ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    next = &str[0];
    result = E();
    result == 1 ? printf("Parsed Successfully") : printf("Parsed Unsuccessfully");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend running this through a debugger, displaying `next` and seeing where, exactly, your expectations are missed. If that doesn't tell you what you need to know, post the results back here.

Comment: Output after printing **next** in the **terminal( )** : 

(a)
(a)
(a)
a)
a)
a)
a)
(a)
(a)
(a)
a)
a)
a)
a)
Parsed Unsuccessfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `T()`:

```
int T(){
  char *temp = next;
  return (next = temp, T1()) || (next = temp, T2()), (next = temp, T3());
}
```

`(next = temp, T3())` is *always* called (there's no short-circuit at the comma before it), and will return `false` in most of your cases, causing all sorts of failures when `T1()` or `T2()` succeed and should have ended the function with success.

Change that line to:

```
return (next = temp, T1()) || (next = temp, T2()) || (next = temp, T3());
```